# Converting software RAID1 to hardware RAID1 without losing data

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid-1

I have a home server running Ubuntu Jaunty and housing a 2 x 2TB RAID1 array. It is a software RAID but I'm looking to pull out those drives and put them in a external RAID enclosure to save space. My question is,

Will I be able to just "plug in" the drives and have it work, or will I have to reformat/rebuild the array?

Does anyone have experience using RAID enclosures?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to format...sorry.  Well, YOU may not have to format, but it won't be able to use the software raid/mdX partitions.  I would backup the data, format and move the drives, initialize the raid array, and restore the backed up files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Raid Controller it may be possible to save the data if you first break the software raid so they are independent disks and then wipe one of the drives (remove all partitions). then you may be able to setup the hardware raid with the disk that still has data as the primary disk and essentially rebuild the array on the Hardware Controller.

*If* this does work it may take many hours to rebuild the array, depending on how much data it needs to copy, and you want to make sure both disks are well cooled during the rebuilding as the long period of sustained reading and writing will generate a lot of heat.

best idea is to back up all essential data as [aking1012](https://superuser.com/questions/212373/converting-software-raid1-to-hardware-raid1-without-losing-data/212375#212375) recommended and then try it